# What is the most elegant way to use generic type as generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, syntax

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way than this example to use generic type as generic parameter:

```
public class Wrapper<TObject>
    where TObject : MyBaseClass
{
}

public class WrapperCollection<TWrapper, TObject> : Collection<TWrapper>
    where TWrapper : Wrapper<TObject>
    where TObject : MyBaseClass
{
}
```

Actually, if I want to initialize an instance of WrapperCollection I would to do it like this:

```
WrapperCollection<Wrapper<MyClass>, MyClass> collection = 
            new WrapperCollection<Wrapper<MyClass>, MyClass>();
```

And as I am not really happy with that, what would be really elegant would be to be able to initialize it like that:

```
WrapperCollection<Wrapper<MyClass>> collection = 
            new WrapperCollection<Wrapper<MyClass>>();
```

So my question is simple: is there a way to do that or is there a more elegant design to use for my CollectionWrapper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `WrapperCollection<T>` *always* contains a collection of `Wrapper<T>`s, then you can do this:

```
public class WrapperCollection<TObject> : Collection<Wrapper<TObject>>
    where TObject : MyBaseClass
{
}

...

WrapperCollection<MyClass> collection = new WrapperCollection<MyClass>();
```

Comment: Looks like `TWrapper` can also be any class derived from `Wrapper`.  In C++ this is easy (use typedef), in C# not so much.

Comment: Quite interesting in a syntax way but not really relevant of the real object. By doing this the user would thing he is creating a collection of TObject, which is not the case. Thank you.